# refer to multiple radio buttons as one object

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a javascript function that displays all of the objects in a class one by one by switching them out when a button is clicked. I want to know if there is any way to refer to a group of radio buttons as one object. I'm new to coding so I'd appreciate a simple answer if possible. Thanks!
(I'm aware this probably isn't the most effective way to do this)
This is the function:

```js
var count = 0;
function addCount() {
    var quests = document.getElementsByClassName("quest");
    if (count > 0) {
        quests[count - 1].style.display = 'none'
    }
    quests[count].style.display = 'block';
    count++;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="#" runat="server">
    <p id="q1" class="quest">1</p>
    <p id="q1" class="quest">2</p>
    <p id="q2" class="quest">3</p>
    <p id="q3" class="quest">4</p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="addCount()" />
    <label>bnt</label>
</form>
```

so far it works with paragraphs but my final goal is to have a quiz that switches questions when you press a button, so I'd like to have a question for each object in the 'quests' array

Comment: You don't have any radio buttons in your code

Comment: I was just trying it out with paragraphs at first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```js
const addCount = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.quest').forEach(e => {
    e.style.display = 'none'
  })
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="#" runat="server">
   <p id="q1" class="quest">1</p>
    <p id="q1" class="quest">2</p>
    <p id="q2" class="quest">3</p>
    <p id="q3" class="quest">4</p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="addCount()" /><label>bnt</label>
</form>
```

Or use jQuery:

```js
const addCount = () => {
  $('.quest').hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="#" runat="server">
   <p id="q1" class="quest">1</p>
    <p id="q1" class="quest">2</p>
    <p id="q2" class="quest">3</p>
    <p id="q3" class="quest">4</p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="addCount()" value="Button">
</form>
```

BTW: I changed the `input` element to `value="Button"`, you cannot use `label` for this.